# Regex to replace webpage meta description apostrophe using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this data:

```
<meta name="description" content="Access Kenya is Kenya's leading corporate Internet service provider and is a technology solutions provider in Kenya with IT and network solutions for your business.Welcome to the Yellow Network.Kenya's leading Corporate and Residential ISP" />;
```

I am using this Regular Expression:

```
<meta +name *=[\"']?description[\"']? *content=[\"']?([^<>'\"]+)[\"']?
```

To get webpage description All works fine but everything stalls everywhere there is an apostrophe.

How do I escape that?

Comment: ... and if the attribute value is wrapped by single quotes, you will have same problem for matching a double quote, right? Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)

Comment: Furthermore, you consider the (not probable) option of a meta without quotes. [See what happen in this case](https://regex101.com/r/hQ1gB0/1).

Comment: @fusion3k i have a fallback plan for that.Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression consider these three options for a `<meta>` node:

```
<meta name="description" content="Some Content" />
<meta name='description' content='Some Content' />
<meta name=description content=Some Content />
```

The third option is not valid HTML, but all can happen, so... you are right.

The simple way is to modify your original regular expression closing tag and using the `?` not-greedy operator:

```
<meta +name *=[\"']?description[\"']? *content=[\"']?(.*?)[\"']? */?>
                                                      └─┘       └───┘
          search zero-or-more characters except following       closing tag characters
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX4aX3/1)**</kbd>

But — also in this case — what happen if you have this meta?

```
<meta content="Some Content" name="description" />
```

Your regular expression will fail.

To **real** match a HTML node, you must use a parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->loadHTML( $yourHtmlString );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$description = $xpath->query( '//meta[@name="description"]/@content' );
echo $description->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

will output:

```
Some Content
```

Yes, it's 5 lines vs 1, but with this method you will match any `<meta name="description">` (also if it contains a third, not valid attribute).

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- Read **[why you can't parse [X]HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262)**